# Generating random numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, random, x86, masm, emu8086

I am new to assembly, and I am having problems generating random numbers.

My code is simple: it generates 100 numbers in the `0-25` range and stores them in an array.

The problem I am experiencing is that when I run the con on the `emu8086` assembler it runs successfully and generates 100 random numbers, that are stored in the array. But when I run it on the `masm611`, it generates a new random number every 4 cycles. Which means the values in the array are consecutive same number for 4 values and then next random value is stored.

Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

range db 25
i db 0                  ;iterator

arr db 15 dup(0)        ; an array

.code
   mov ax,@data
   mov ds,ax

   mov bx,offset arr    ;getting the adress of the arr in bx
    L1:

    mov ah,2ch      
    int 21h

    mov ah,0  
    mov al,dl            ;using dl by seeing  2ch details
    div range            ; so the number is in range


    mov [bx],ah          ;ah has remainder as using 8 bits div and  
    inc bx               ;moving to the next index

    inc i
    cmp i,100
    jbe L1


mov ah,4ch               ;returning control
int 21h 
end
```

Is there is a problem in my code? Do I need to add something? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK the system timer only changes once every 1/18.2 s. Basing your return values  directly on that doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: Use the [RDRAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) instruction! ;-)

Comment: @Michael what should I do for it?

Comment: Don't rely on external things (timer in your case). Implement some well known RNG, for example [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register). Also note that by using modulo operator to fit numbers in range numbers become not uniformly distributed (e.g. 0..255 mod 240 makes numbers 0..15 appear twice as often).

Comment: There are several useful links in the "Related" panel over there --->>

Comment: The problem is solved by making delay in the iterations. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem of your code is that it does not generate random numbers at all. Because the system clock is not random number generator. I would say, it is very non-random number generator.

The first time read after the start of the program still can be considered "random", but only if you run the program manually in random moment in time.

All next numbers will be not random at all.

This way, the value read from the system clock is suitable for use as a seed (starting value) of some other algorithm for generation of (pseudo)random numbers.

The random (and pseudo random) number generators are complex topic, that need some study. Start at least with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

BTW, despite of the complexity of the topic as a whole, some random number generators are simple enough to be implemented by beginner programmers. For example [middle-square-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method). Try to implement it in assembly language by multiplying the current seed AX by itself and form the next number by the middle 4 hexadecimal digits of the result:

```
; here ax contains the previous number

    mul ax
    mov al, ah
    mov ah, dl 

; here ax contains the next pseudo random number.
```

Comment: Thanks it was informative but I solved my problem by setting a `dummy loop` which is causing a delay in iterations. The problem was that masm611 is too fast and before  that the milliseconds are changing in the dl register by 2ch , it is storing the value before it is changed.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Well, actually you didn't. You simply camouflaged the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To build upon johnfound's answer, you could make a more robust random number generator by running the middle-square method he described with a Weyl sequence. This is based on ideas from *Middle Square Weyl Sequence RNG*, published by Bernard Widynski on 4th April 2017.

An assembly implementation could be built along the following lines:

```
    mul ax      ; square random number
    add cx, bx  ; calculate next iteration of Weyl sequence
    add ax, cx  ; add Weyl sequence
    mov al, ah  ; get lower byte of random number from higher byte of ax
    mov ah, dl  ; get higher byte of random number from lower byte of dx
    ...         ; use new random number stored in ax
```

A few notes about the above code:

- The random number is stored in `ax`.
- The initial seed is stored in `bx` (you could for instance use something derived from the system's clock). The seed must be odd and non-zero in the 8 upper bits.
- The Weyl sequence is stored in `cx`, and obtained by adding `bx` at each iteration.

Unlike the standard middle-square method, combining it with a Weyl sequence prevents convergence towards 0 of the random number sequence. I recommend reading the publication mentioned above for additional information.